# Executing a function based on a click event on an html element in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

Hi I'm trying to get a function defined in my controller to execute when I press on a specific area of a picture. I'm using an html map to define the areas of my picture (code below)

```
<mvc:View id="Main" controllerName="Demo.picture.controller.Main" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
<App id="idAppControl">
    <pages>
        <Page title="{i18n>title}">
            <content>
                    <Image src = "Some image source" alt="Image" useMap="Map"/>
            </content>
        </Page>
    </pages>
</App>
<html:map name="Map" id="Map">
    <html:area id= "area_1" shape="rect" coords= "0,0,240,215" alt="Chart" onclick="???"/>
    <html:area id = "area_2" shape="rect" coords="240,0,480,215" alt="Start" onclick="???"/>
</html:map> </mvc:View>
```

Not sure if using onclick is the right way of doing this.

Controller code:

```
sap.ui.define([

"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller"], function (Controller) {
"use strict";

return Controller.extend("Demo.picture.controller.Main", {


    SomeMethodFoo: function () {
        "method to be executed when area_1 is pressed"
    },

    SomeMethodGoo: function () {
        "method to be executed when area_2 is pressed"
    }

});});
```

Is it possible to attach an eventHandler for a onclick event to these areas? Or is there some other way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that it would be something like this:

```
onclick="sap.ui.getCore().byId('__xmlview0').getController().SomeMethodFoo()"
```

but your need to manage yourself to know your view ID, which won't be always '__xmlview0'